# Proper way to write rspecs in rails

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails

I am new in Rspecs so the following code i have wrote is it correct...I have used simple Rspec. Currently Rspec running correctly, but clients prospective what changes need to do?
If someone can take a look at my code and help me out that would be appreciated....

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rails_helper'

describe User do
describe "fails" do
    it "to create without email" do
      user = User.create(:first_name => "test", :last_name => "test",:email => "")
      user.errors.messages[:email][0].should eq "can't be blank"
    end
end

describe "fails" do
    it "to create without data" do
      user = User.create(:first_name => "", :last_name => "", :email => "", :status => "")
      user.errors.messages[:email][0].should eq "can't be blank"
    end
end

describe "fail" do
    it "to create without a valid email" do
      user = User.create(:first_name => "", :last_name => "", :email => "test@test1", :status => "")
      expect(user).to be_valid, lambda { "expected valid email" }
    end
end

describe "pass" do
    it "to supports 2 letter domain qualifiers" do
      user = User.create(:first_name => "", :last_name => "", :email => "test@test1.ca", :status => "")
      user.save!
    end
end

describe "pass" do
    it "to supports 4 letter domain qualifiers" do
      user = User.create(:first_name => "", :last_name => "", :email => "test@test1.some", :status => "")
      user.save!
    end
end
end

describe "pass" do
    it "to supports 4 and more letter domain qualifiers" do
      user = User.create(:first_name => "", :last_name => "", :email => "test@test1.super", :status => "")
      user.save!
    end
end

describe "pass" do
    it "to without first name" do
        user = User.new
        user.first_name = ""
        user.last_name = "Test"
        user.status = "active"
        user.email = "test127@test.com"
        user.save!
    end
end

describe "pass" do
    it "to without last name" do
        user = User.new
        user.first_name = "Test"
        user.last_name = ""
        user.status = "active"
        user.email = "test127@test.com"
        user.save!
    end
end

describe "pass" do
    it "to without status" do
        user = User.new
        user.first_name = "Test"
        user.last_name = "Test"
        user.status = ""
        user.email = "test127@test.com"
        user.save!
    end
end

describe "pass" do
    it "to create new record without first name, last name and status" do
      user = User.create(:first_name => "", :last_name => "", :email => "test@test1.com", :status => "")
      user.save!
    end
end

describe "pass" do
    it "to create new record with all parameter" do
        user = User.new
        user.first_name = "Test"
        user.last_name = "Test"
        user.status = "active"
        user.email = "test127@test.com"
        user.save!
    end
end

describe "pass" do
    it "to update record" do
        user = User.find_by_id(1127)
        user.first_name = "Test"
        user.last_name = "Test"
        user.status = "active"
        user.email = "test127@test.com"
        user.save!
    end
end
```

Comment: where are your tests? :)

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't have to require both `spec_helper` and `rails_helper`. `spec_helper` is already required in `rails_helper`. `spec_helper` is for specs which don't depend on Rails (for example classes in the lib directory). `rails_helper` is for specs which do depend on Rails (for example your models and controllers)
2. Try to run your specs with `--format documentation` flag to see if your example and context names does make sense. In this case I'm sure you can improve it.

Instead of

```
describe "fails" do
  it "to create without email" do
    ...
  end
end
```

it's more meaningful to write

```
describe "when creating user without email" do
  it "adds error" do
    ...
  end
end
```

and so on. You can also add examples like `does not create new record`

3. Instead of using model directly you can use factories - https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails
4. Your `pass` examples didn't test anything at all. Instead of writing this

   user = User.create(...)
   user.save!

you can write

```
expect { User.new(...).save }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
```

When you use factories I'm sure that proper specs should looks like this

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe User do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.build :user, first_name: 'First name', last_name: 'Last name', email: 'email@gmail.com' }

  context 'when user want to create account without email' do
    before { user.email = nil }

    it 'does not save user record' do
      expect { user.save }.not_to change(User, :count)
    end
  end
 end
```

Comment: thanks @dziamber...your answer is very helpful for me.... I have some google it ran the above spec like this. is it correct?

 it "fails without a valid email" do
  user = User.create(:first_name => "", :last_name => "", :email => "test@test", :status => "")
  expect(user).to be_valid, lambda { "expected valid email" }
 end

Comment: Please update your post instead of pasting code in comment because it's not readable now

Answer (score 0):

```
it "fails without email" do
    user = User.create(:first_name => "test", :last_name => "test",:email => "")
    user.errors.messages[:email][0].should eq "can't be blank"
end

it "fails without parameters" do
    user = User.create(:first_name => "", :last_name => "", :email => "", :status => "")
    user.errors.messages[:email][0].should eq "can't be blank"
end

it "fails without a valid email" do
    user = User.create(:first_name => "", :last_name => "", :email => "test@test", :status => "")
    expect(user).to be_valid, lambda { "expected valid email" }
end

it "passes without first name" do
    pre_count = User.count
    user = User.new
    user.first_name = ""
    user.last_name = "Test"
    user.status = "active"
    user.email = "test127@test.com"
    user.save!
    count = User.count
    tot_count = pre_count + 1
    count.should be tot_count
    user.email.should eq "test127@test.com"
    user.first_name.should eq nil
    user.last_name.should eq "Test"
    user.status.should eq :active
end
```

Comment: Did you checked `FactoryGirl` gem? Also good practice is to have only one expectation per one example